# How to create Video with mp3 using NSMutableArray of Images IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I want to create a video with mp3 using NSMutableArray of Images.I have Array of multiple images and i want to create a video with custom mp3 file (user selected mp3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this link is usefull for you..
[GitHub Link](https://github.com/caferrara/img-to-video)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Simple Animation Using UIImageView](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-animation-uiimageview/) and play thw selected mp3 file as background music using  `AVAudioPlayer` .

```
 //Animation
 // Load images
    NSArray *imageNames = @[@"win_1.png", @"win_2.png", @"win_3.png", @"win_4.png",
                        @"win_5.png", @"win_6.png", @"win_7.png", @"win_8.png",
                        @"win_9.png", @"win_10.png", @"win_11.png", @"win_12.png",
                        @"win_13.png", @"win_14.png", @"win_15.png", @"win_16.png"];

    NSMutableArray *images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i = 0; i < imageNames.count; i++) {
        [images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[imageNames objectAtIndex:i]]];
    }

    // Normal Animation
    UIImageView *animationImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 95, 86, 193)];
    animationImageView.animationImages = images;
    animationImageView.animationDuration = 0.5;

    [self.view addSubview:animationImageView];
    [animationImageView startAnimating];

//background music
 //start a background sound
    NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Soothing_Music2_Long" ofType: @"mp3"];
    NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:soundFilePath ];    
    myAudioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:nil];
    myAudioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1; //infinite loop
    [myAudioPlayer play];
```